# PrintQueue Addjob hang issue in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, printing, freeze

I have a question about printing issue.

I have a function call contains below code:

```
PrintQueue.UserPrintTicket = Ticket;
PrintQueue.AddJob(ShortDocumentName, XpsDocumentFile, false);
```

Ticket is the type of `PrintTicket`, `ShortDocumentName` is string type of doc name, `XpsDocumentFile` is string type of xps file name.

these two lines of code run successfully in Windows 7, but will hang in Windows 10.

Is there any work around or solution for this issue?

Comment: I today use the below method, but it is not work fine in Hard printer.

using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(XpsDocumentFile))
using (var printStream = new PrintQueueStream(PrintQueue, ShortDocumentName, true))
      {
        fileStream.BaseStream.CopyTo(printStream);
      }

Comment: var file = File.ReadAllBytes(XpsDocumentFile);
using (var job = PrintQueue.AddJob(ShortDocumentName, Ticket))
using (var stream = job.JobStream)
{
      stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
}

Also this method I tried, and it will crash in Windows 7.

Comment: Does any one from Microsoft could provide the reason about the issue?

Answer (score 2):

How about trying PrintDialog?

[PrintQueue.AddJob hangs when printing to non-xps based printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145399/printqueue-addjob-hangs-when-printing-to-non-xps-based-printers)

Actually, I wanted to write in comments, but I have not that authority yet.
So I posted the answer. I'm sorry if I used it wrong.